# Rotational mechanics - ball climbing a step

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-kinematics

A wheel of radius, $R$ and weight, $W$ stands in front of a step of height, $h$ where h is less than R.

What is the least horizontal force $F$ which must be applied at the axle of the wheel to allow it to rise up the step.

After finding torque, $\tau$ of the force applied, about the point where the normal force is exerted by the step, I get:

$$\tau = F(R-h)$$

However, I don't understand what I should equate this to. How to ensure that this torque allows the wheel to rise up the step?

Comment: You need an angle so you want to equate it to a torque expression with an angle.

Comment: @Magpie I don't understand. How would we need an angle? The wheel is rising up the step that's all we know.

Comment: Is that the _only_ torque acting on the wheel? There is another that is opposing your efforts to lift it up over the step.

Comment: @G.Paily And what would that force be?

Comment: The torque due to the weight of the wheel.

Comment: @G.Paily But that will also be in the clockwise direction, same as the one we are trying to push it. Moreover, wouldn't that be balanced out by the torque due to the normal force?

Comment: When the wheel just starts to lift up, it is no longer in contact with the ground. So the normal force from the ground goes to zero. It is still in contact with the step, so there is a normal force from there, but we have taken that spot as our pivot, so it will contribute no torque. The weight acts through the center of mass, and creates a counterclockwise torque.

Comment: @G.Paily Oh... I see now. Well thanks for that clarification.

Comment: @Gummybears, you need to equate the torque from the force (which is trying to rotate the wheel up the step) to the torque from the wheel's weight (which is trying to rotate the wheel down the step).  Note that the torque from the wheel's weight is acting through the center of mass of the wheel.

Comment: @DavidWhite Ahhh..... This question brought back memories! xD

Answer (score 2):

The torque you need to overcome is the force of gravity multiplied by the horizontal distance from the center of gravity to the step's edge.

This distance can be computed from the angle $\theta$ between the line joining the contact point to the center of mass, and the vertical.

$$\cos\theta = \frac{R-h}{R}$$

And the horizontal distance is

$$d=R\sin\theta$$

This means the horizontal force needed obeys this equation:

$$F R \cos\theta = mgR\sin\theta$$

Answer (score 1):

The key phrase to notice here is that you are being asked for the least horizontal force.

If you use a different expression for torque, you should be able to find the least horizontal force by figuring out what the minimum angle needed is.

Remember:

$$\tau=\underline{\mathbf{r}}\times\underline{\mathbf{F}}$$

Comment: Minimum angle for what? What angle would we take? BTW, the answer is given in terms of W, R, and h.

Comment: Do you understand what the question asks for when it asks for the "least horizontal force"? This is quite important to solving this problem. Once you know that you can just equate the lhs of torque with the rhs and rearrange to get your solution.

Comment: Well not exactly I guess. Basically a force you need to overcome the opposing force. But the opposing force is the downward weight of the ball as well as the normal by the step. Not sure how to equate that.

Comment: @Gummybears do you know about cross products?

Comment: Yes of course I do.